# How to set .NET 8.0 in DevOps Release pipeline?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

When using Azure Web App Deploy Task you must choose Runtime Stack that will be used in the Azure Web App.

I have recently updated from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and to my surprise you can set .NET 8 everywhere needed (like Pipeline build, Azure General Settings), but not in the Azure Web App Deploy Task where it is missing from dropdown and that causes your Web App service to fallback to .NET 7, which can make your app stop running.

How can you fix that broken pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from the screenshot on @wade-zhou-msft's answer if the App Service is deploying to Windows or Linux, of if there is a difference between OS'es.

However for my Linux App Service, I had to use a slightly different value: `DOTNETCORE|8.0`

To copy [my answer on the VS dev community channel](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-deploy-pipeline-missing-Net-Core-/10528836#T-ND10620300):

> I was able to use v4 of the Azure App Service deploy task to manually enter “DOTNETCORE|8.0” - note the slightly different format from the selectable options. Only tested for Azure Resource Manager for Linux.
>
> [image: Task version]
>
> [image: ARM]
>
> [image: Linux]
>
> [image: Stack]
>
> Logs after deploy:
>
> [image: Logs]

Comment: Thank you @Stajs! That works for me. You can also use Azure Web App task version 1.0 and it works the same good. The crucial part was to use "slightly different value": DOTNETCORE|8.0 and not 8.0 (DOTNETCORE|8.0)

Answer (score 5):

Dotnetcore - 8.0 is currently in [Early Access](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/early_access.md), the option `8.0 (DOTNETCORE|8.0)` is NOT added to the task Azure App Service deploy yet.

The field is editable in the task, you can choose the `7.0 (DOTNETCORE|7.0)` from the dropdown list and change it to `8.0 (DOTNETCORE|8.0)`.

[image]

[image]

The option request has been reported to product team, you can check the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-deploy-pipeline-missing-Net-Core/10528836?sort=newest&ftype=problem) for the details.

Comment: Following your answer I set 8 in this dropdown/input field, but after release it set Stack to undefined and stopped the web api :(

Comment: The Runtime Stack on my web app is successfully updated to `8.0 (dotnetcore - 8.0)`, it's recommended to raise a new ticket and add the log snippet and screenshot for further checking.